# Collision detection of two circles rotating around fixed points in 2D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, rotational-kinematics, geometry

Recently I have learned how to predict the time of collision between two circles moving linearly. Positions of $P$ and $Q$ after time $t$ are:
$P(t) = P_0 + vPt$
$Q(t) = Q_0 + vQt$
The goal was to find such an instant ($t$) when distance between circle centers equal to sum of their radii:
$P(t) - Q(t) = rP + rQ$
$(P_0 + vPt) - (Q_0 + vQt) = rP + rQ$
$P_0 - Q_0 + (vP - vQ)t = rP + rQ$
$(P_0 - Q_0 + (vP - vQ)t)^2 = (rP + rQ)^2$
$(P_0 - Q_0 + (vP - vQ)t) * (P_0 - Q_0 + (vP - vQ)t) = (rP + rQ)^2$
Some parts of the equation can be reduced:
$A = P_0 - Q_0$
$B = vP - vQ$
$(A + Bt) * (A + Bt) = (rP + rQ)^2$
$A * A + 2(A * B)t + (B * B)t^2 = (rP + rQ)^2$
$A * A + 2(A * B)t + (B * B)t^2 - (rP + rQ)^2 = 0$
This leads to the quadratic equation $at^2 + bt + c = 0$, where:
$a=B * B, b=A * B, c=A * A - (rP + rQ)^2$
From this $t$ is resolvable:
$t = \frac{(b ± \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac})}{2a}$
Discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ has no solutions (no collision) when it is less than zero. Has exactly one solution (touch at some instant) when it is equal to zero. Has more than one solution (collision) when it is greater than zero.

What I'm trying to solve is **the time of collision between circles rotating around their fixed points**.

$P(t) = P_0 + \omega Pt$ (or $P_c$ + radial vector $P_cP_0$ rotated by $\omega Pt$)
$Q(t) = Q_0 + \omega Qt$ (or $Q_c$ + radial vector $Q_cQ_0$ rotated by $\omega Qt$)
The goal is to find such an instant when distance between circle centers equal to sum of their radii:
$P(t) - Q(t) = rP + rQ$
$(P_0 + \omega Pt) - (Q_0 + \omega Qt) = rP + rQ$, or:
($P_c$ + radial vector $P_cP_0$ rotated by $\omega Pt) - (Q_c$ + radial vector $Q_cQ_0$ rotated by $\omega Qt)$ = $rP + rQ$

But at this point I'm pretty much stuck. Is it possible to solve this like I did with linear case (quadratic equation) or should I consider completely different priori collision detection algorithm to reach the solution?

[image: SKETCHES]
Note that P small and large radii are constant (same holds for Q). But P's small radius is not necessarily the same as Q's (same holds for large radius). $P_c$ and $Q_c$ centers are fixed.

Comment: I don't think this problem can be solved analytically, but maybe I misunderstood the question. Can you provide with a sketch with an example. From the equations you wrote it still looks like linear motion to me.

Comment: @ja72 I painted sketches of some rotation and detection cases.

Comment: Do the centers $P_c$ and $Q_c$ undergo any motion, or are they fixed?

Comment: $P_c$ and $Q_c$ centers are fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie I suggest to vote for migration to the MathSE.